# ImageView can't load image(jpg,png,...)

Tags: android, image, bitmap, imageview

I'm trying to load an image from my res/drawable folder.I used the guide from Android Developers [Link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).
For some reason it isnt working.The only error I get is "SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length",which I researched.Appearently it has to do with custom keyboards but I'm not using text input at all.The app itself isnt crashing.I hope you guys can help me :)
The layout file just contains a RelativeLayout with an ImageView.

```
public class PixelActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pixel);
    String uri = "@drawable-hdpi/testbild.png";
    final int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());


    final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);

    //int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    //int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
    //String imageType = options.outMimeType;
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {

        public void run()
        {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageResource, options);


            iv.post(new Runnable()
            {

                public void run()
                {
                    iv.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResources(getResources(),imageResource,iv.getWidth(),iv.getHeight()));
                    //iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.testbild);
                }
            });
        }
    });






}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
{
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if(height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth)
    {
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float)height/(float)reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float)width/(float)reqWidth);

        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResources(Resources res, int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
{
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options,reqWidth,reqHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

}

Comment: Try runOnUiThread instead of view.post. View.post sometimes just doesn't get called at all. Only Handler.post and Activity.runOnUiThread are always working for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
String uri = "@drawable-hdpi/testbild.png";
```

That is invalid. Delete the `-hdpi` portion and the `.png` portion, and try again. Or, switch to providing all three parameters to `getIdentifier()`:

```
final int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("testbild", "drawable", getPackageName());
```